# SQL Server replication when there is no data on one server

Tags: sql-server, replication

The software works with the bases of the main server. When it becomes unavailable, they connect to the backup (to which we are building a replication) and continue to work. As soon as the main server appears on the network and becomes available, work switches back to it.

That is, we need to have a mirror copy of all data on the backup in case the main one fails, and then transfer all the work that was worked on to the backup. If the main one is available, to the main one so as not to lose the piece of work that was done while the main one was not available.

What are the possibilities in SQL Server for replication?

While this is not set up, did anyone have experience. Replication on 2 servers.

Comment: Look into Always-on Availability Groups

Comment: Does the software write to the database or only read from it? Which version and edition of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you would like to have an Always-On solution:

> Always On SQL Server is a High Availability and Disaster Recovery
> solution introduced in SQL Server 2012. It increases the availability
> by providing a failover environment for Availability Databases that
> failover together.

There is a good stairway post about this on SQL Server Central.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-alwayson

Comment: Thank you I will try this article